# script is skipping first few rows

Tags: php, html, dom, row, domparser

I have simple html dom parser script, but when I run it, it skips first few rows.
Bellow is the snippet of my code:

```
......
$record_find='second';
    foreach($html->find('table#GridView1') as $e){

                 if($record_find=='first'){ $record_find="second";continue;}
         $i=1;
                foreach($e->find('tr') as $e1){
.......
```

I'm parsing data from this "http://krushimitra.co.in/1.html" url. And in this, the script skips first three rows Achanta, coconut, paddy respectively, and detects all further rows continues. Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you try to use a plugin like http://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/ to parse HTML to DOM. Then you can implement your logic behind this. I didn't use it before, but I think its behaviors are same with Nokogiri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to code like below in your script and any html parser DOM will works with this. You need to use record find first instead of second.

```
......
$record_find='first';
    foreach($html->find('table#GridView1') as $e){

                 if($record_find=='first')
         $i=1;
                foreach($e->find('tr') as $e1){
.......
```